# How to get rid of gap where borders intersect?

Tags: html, css

I have a table made of divs, and borders on the cells where some horizontal and vertical borders overlap. In the case where the colors of the borders are different (in this case black and transparent), there's a tiny gap where the borders overlap. Is there a way to get rid of this gap? I would just like to have the black border to take priority over the transparent border.

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
}

.section {
  flex: 40%;
}

.bot {
  border-top: 4px solid transparent;
}

.right {
  border-left: 4px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top left section"></div>
  <div class="top right section"></div>
  <div class="bot left section"></div>
  <div class="bot right section"></div>
  <div class="bot left section"></div>
  <div class="bot right section"></div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/twshzrdm/

Comment: when it's transparent make it 0px and not 4px

Comment: Remove the `border-top` altogether. https://jsfiddle.net/Lxobg9ak/